# Searching for an element in a 2D matrix using std::vector

Tags: c++, stl

```
bool findInMatrix(int x, vector<vector<int>> &arr)
{
    //    Write your code here.
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<arr[0].size();j++)
        {
            if(arr[i][j] == x)
                return true;    
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can anybody help me with this soln, I am able to pass all the testcases but getting TLE!!!

Comment: It could be that the inner vectors do not all have the same size, so use arr[i].size()

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem in the inner for loop. You are looping over the size of the 0th vector, when you should be looping over the size of ith vector. Each vector can have a different size.

```
bool findInMatrix(int x, vector<vector<int>> &arr) {

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); j++) {
            if(arr[i][j] == x) {
                return true;    
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Still getting TLE!!

Comment: @SHASHANKJAIN you have not mentioned anything about the problem statement. Your approach itself might be wrong. This is the fastest method to find an element in an unsorted 2D matrix. You cannot get faster.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to use STL 's find which could be optimal.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector,std::find;

bool findInMatrix(int x, vector<vector<int>> &arr)
{
    //    Write your code here.     
    for(auto& rows:arr){    
        auto it = find(rows.begin(), rows.end(), x);
        if (it != rows.end())
        {
            return true;
        }   
    }     
    
    return false;
}


int main(){
    
    vector<vector<int>> arr;
    int rows = 5;
    int cols = 4;

    // init with random data
    for(int i = 0; i<rows;i++){
        vector<int> elems;
         for(int j = 0; j<cols;j++){            
            elems.push_back(rand()%100); 
        }  
        arr.push_back(elems);
    }

    // peek the data
    for(const auto & rows:arr){
        for(const auto &elem:rows ){
            std::cout<<elem<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }

    int x = arr[3][2];

    std::cout<<"searching for "<<x<<"\n";
    // search for the element
    std::cout<<findInMatrix(x,arr)<<"\n"; // returns true

    std::cout<<findInMatrix(9999,arr)<<"\n"; // returns false

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the soln, but its time complexity is not efficient, Instead I come with the following soln
'''
bool findInMatrix(int x, vector<vector<int>> &arr)
{
    int n = arr.size();
    int m = arr[0].size();
    int row = 0, column = m-1;
    while((row>=0 && row<n)&&((column>=0 && column<m)))
    {
        if(arr[row][column]==x)
            return true;
        else if(arr[row][column]<x)
            row++;
        else
            column--;
    }
    return false;
}
'''